# Ember.js - Propagate event up the controller/router chain

Tags: javascript, events, controller, ember.js, router

In Ember.js, events that aren't handled in the controller propagate up the router chain to the application route (see http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/ for more details).

Is there a way to define an event handler in the controller that allows the event to continue propagating to the router?

```
App.SampleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  myEvent: function(obj) {
    this.set('aVariable', true);
  }
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    myEvent: function(obj) {
      this.transitionTo('something');
    }
  }
});
```

Is there a way for the myEvent handler in CarsController to set its internal state variable but also kick the event up the chain to the application route? I'm aware of this:

```
App.__container__.lookup('router:main').send('myEvent', obj);
```

but it uses Ember internals. I was hoping there was a more standard way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to achieve this could be:

```
App.SampleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: 'application',
  myEvent: function(obj) {
    this.set('aVariable', true);

    this.get('controllers.application').send('myEvent');
  }
});
```

Working [demo](http://jsbin.com/oduhom/4/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Doesn't work (tried using Ember.js 1.0.0-rc.6). I wondered if that might be it also, so I tried returning true and false but neither worked.

Comment: @kleinsch adde also a demo jsbin: http://jsbin.com/oduhom/3/edit sending the event to the application controller should work

Comment: @kleinsch removed the deprecation, using the needs API is now the correct way to get a dependency to another controller, sorry for all the fuss

Comment: Awesome! controllerFor is deprecated, so you should probably do it like this - http://jsbin.com/ozecoj/1/edit . Update the code in the answer and I'll accept!